# Flask application to be visible in local network

Tags: flask, localhost, vmware

I have a Flask application running under VMware workstation.

1. VMware uses NAT and virtual machine has IP **192.168.52.132**
2. I use **app.run(host='0.0.0.0')** to run my application
3. I can see it running in browser if I type http://localhost:5000
4. I can also see it running from my host machine if I type http://192.168.52.132:5000 or http://localhost:5000
5. netstat -tupln | grep ':5000' gives me:

   **tcp || 0 ||  0 0.0.0.0:5000 || 0.0.0.0:* || LISTEN || 44937/python**
6. As suggested in similar topics here, I did:

   **iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 5000 -j ACCEPT**

Unfortunately, if I try to open http://192.168.52.132:5000 from different machine inside the same WiFi network, I only get "Cannot connect to destination (192.168.52.132).

What else should I do to make my app visible from other devices?
Thank you.

p.s.
Running application with **debug=True** didn't help me too.

Comment: `VMware uses NAT` so your local network is not `192.168.52.0`, this network is only between your VM and your host. Your host must redirect the traffic it receives to your VM.

Comment: Hi @njzk2, I switched to Bridge mode, new IP is 192.168.1.9 and searching it from other devices I can see my application. Bt to make this work with NAT, should I do changes in my VMware profile or is it something with editing http conf file on my host machine?

Comment: is has nothing to do with either vmware or http. It requires port forwarding. On your host, add an iptables configuration line to activate it. See http://www.systutorials.com/816/port-forwarding-using-iptables/

Comment: I have a similar problem. Has your problem solved?